# Chart Series Transparent Background

Tags: vb.net, mschart

After adding my data I want to make a simple chart and I want to make some modification.

I want to make the chart background transparent or change it to my panel color and remove the lines on the background as you can see. Also, can I make a swift graph line?

[image: chart image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already made the outside of the chart transparent, probably with:

```
Chart1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent
```

But that does not make the inside of that chart, the **ChartArea**, transparent. That can be achieved like this:

```
ChartArea1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent
```

Removing the lines on the background, the **Axis Major Grid**, can be done this way:

```
ChartArea1.AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = False
ChartArea1.AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = False
```

As for whether you can make a Swift line graph; please give it a try, and ask another separate question here on StackoverFlow when you get stuck.